# How can I change the color of the circle based on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

I want to know how I can change the color of the circular part based in the relevant color clicked I've written a function but it is not working. Can someone help me?

[image]

The Javascript code was written to change the color. Here I've tried to take the background color of the circle and change it to the color of the button clicked, but I can't seem to find a way to access the card; before in CSS where I've set the background color.

Another problem was to extract the color from the span when clicked in order to change the color of the circle to that.

```js
function productCardColorChange1() {
    document.getElementById('card').before.style.background = 
    document.getElementById('color1').style.background;
}
```

```css
//this is the css code
    .container .card {
      position: relative;
      width: 320px;
      height: 450px;
      background: #232323;
      border-radius: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

   .container .card: before{
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: #9bdc28;
     clip-path:circle(150px at 80% 20%);
     transition: 1s;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="card" id="card">
            <div class="imgBx" id="imgBx">
                <img src = "shoes.png">
            </div>
            <div class="contentBx">
                <h2>Nike shoes</h2>
                <div class="size">
                    <h3>Size :</h3>
                    <span>7</span>
                    <span>8</span>
                    <span>9</span>
                    <span>10</span>
  
                </div>
                <div class="color">
                    <h3>Color :</h3>
                    <span id="color1" onclick="productCardColorChange1()"></span>
                    <span id="color2"></span>
                    <span id="color3"></span>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't show any attempt of trying to modify anything. What method are you wanting to use to edit the color? I assume you are using a `PNG`  and wanting to change the background color for display but you haven't provided a `PNG` of that item or shown how you want to pass the color selection/change to modify the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more efficient to use `addEventListener` if you are targeting more than one element.

```js
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.color > span')

colors.forEach(elm => {
   elm.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const bgColor = window.getComputedStyle(event.target).backgroundColor
    if(bgColor) {
     document.getElementById('card').style.backgroundColor = bgColor
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#card {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #232323;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .card: before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #9bdc28;
  clip-path:circle(150px at 80% 20%);
  transition: 1s;
}

.color {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.color > h3 {
  margin: 0;
 }
 
.color > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width:  30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#color1 {
  background-color: green;
}
#color2 {
  background-color: pink;
}
#color3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="card" id="card">
            <div class="imgBx" id="imgBx">
                <img src = "shoes.png">
            </div>
            <div class="contentBx">
                <h2>Nike shoes</h2>
                <div class="size">
                    <h3>Size :</h3>
                    <span>7</span>
                    <span>8</span>
                    <span>9</span>
                    <span>10</span>
  
                </div>
                <div class="color">
                    <h3>Color :</h3>
                    <span id="color1"></span>
                    <span id="color2"></span>
                    <span id="color3"></span>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```